# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env Android

Tags: java, android

```
11-11 15:11:03.770 10425-10476/com.techworld.example E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 1, error: Too many open files
11-11 15:11:03.785 10425-10476/com.techworld.example A/OpenGLRenderer: Encountered EGL error 12291 EGL_BAD_ALLOC during rendering
11-11 15:11:03.800 10425-12845/com.techworld.example E/art: ashmem_create_region failed for 'indirect ref table': Too many open files
11-11 15:11:03.800 10425-12845/com.techworld.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                       Process: com.techworld.example, PID: 10425
                                                                       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:921)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:989)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1131)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

well first one i run the async task it works fine but if i run the async task second time it shows this error and force close ,do not know what is causing problem

After deleting and using alternate stuff on doubted classes i have figure it out that this zip class is causing problem ,replacing this class works totally fine ,do not know what is error in this class

```
ZipUtils.java
package com.techworld.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class ZipUtil {

    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 4;

    /*
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        zipFile("C:/tmp/demo", "C:/tmp/demo.zip", true);
    }
     */

    public static void zipitman(String source,String zipFile, boolean excludeparent) throws Exception {
        zipFile(source, zipFile, excludeparent);
    }

    static public void zipFile(String fileToZip, String zipFile, boolean excludeContainingFolder)
            throws IOException {
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile));
        File srcFile = new File(fileToZip);
        if(excludeContainingFolder && srcFile.isDirectory()) {
            for(String fileName : srcFile.list()) {
                addToZip("", fileToZip + "/" + fileName, zipOut);
            }
        } else {
            addToZip("", fileToZip, zipOut);
        }

        zipOut.flush();
        zipOut.close();

    }

    static private void addToZip(String path, String srcFile, ZipOutputStream zipOut)
            throws IOException {
        File file = new File(srcFile);
        String filePath = "".equals(path) ? file.getName() : path + "/" + file.getName();
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            for (String fileName : file.list()) {
                addToZip(filePath, srcFile + "/" + fileName, zipOut);
            }
        } else {
            zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filePath));
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                zipOut.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: i am doing a lot of work but seems error is coming in zipfile

Comment: @AndroidBeginnerJhon you need to figure out the source of this we can't predict it without the code! My guess its the way that you deal with the response but either way you have to post your code

Comment: hello guys the culprit class is added in original post,after removing this class not outofmemory error

Comment: You are not closing `FileInputStream`s

Comment: oh thanks didnot see that my bad looking for big error and miss this :)